# unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'float' on an array

Tags: python, list, graph, error-handling, floating-point

**Question:** (Solution at bottom)

I have an array of data, that I wish to plot a graph of then fit an exponential decay model over that is weighted by 1/uncertainty^2 (here the variable is called ampserr). Running the code will produce the graph, but not fit the model and produces the error message:

`unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'float'`

I saw on other questions that, (i think) i need to use a for loop to somehow run over every item in the array, but wasn't really sure how to do that. The code is a few hundred lines long and pretty hard to break up, so I'll just post the bit that's most relevant but it won't work on it's own. Happy to post the full code if someone wants though. To clarify, ampserr is not an integer value. Anyone able to help me get past this error?

**Code:**

```
    stderr = result.params['amp'].stderr
    if not stderr:
        stderr = 1e8
    if stderr < stderrThreshold and result.params['amp'] > minimumAmplitude:
        amps.append(result.params['amp'].value) 
        ampserr.append(stderr)
        ts.append((MaestroT*(n+1)-(DeadTime/2)))
    
    ## Plot decay curve & settings for decayplot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
    ax.errorbar(ts, amps, xerr=2, yerr=sqrt(amps), fmt="ko-", capsize = 5, capthick= 2, elinewidth=3, markersize=5)
    plt.xlabel('Time  /s', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Counts Recorded in the Previous 15 seconds', fontsize=16)
    plt.title("Decay curve of P-31 by $β^+$ emission", fontsize=16)
    

    ## Fit decay curve
    emodel = Model(expdecay)
    
    if rawdata == 1:
        print(ampserr)
        print(amps)
        print(ts)
        
    decayresult = emodel.fit(amps, x=ts, weights=(1/(ampserr)^(2))+1e-8), t=150, A=90)
    ax.plot(ts, decayresult.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')
```

**Trying with the exponentional operator as Gionni suggested:**

`decayresult = emodel.fit(amps, x=ts, weights=(1/((ampserr)**(2))+1e-8), t=150, A=90)`

**Solution:**

`decayresult = emodel.fit(amps, x=ts, weights=(1/((np.array(ampserr)**(1))+1e-8)), t=150, A=90)` as suggested by Gionni

Comment: The exponentiation operator in python is `**`, not `^`.

Comment: I tried it, but that didn't work out either. `unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: 2 solutions: 1) list comprehension `weights=[(1/(ampserr_el)^(2))+1e-8) for ampserr_el in ampserr]` 2) use numpy and convert `ampserr` to np array `np.array(ampserr)`, then you can do operation between a scalar and an array. In my opinion the second solution is better

Comment: That did it, thank you. Would you want to make it an answer so i can mark it for other peoples future reference? Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to exponentiate a list with a number, which, as the error suggest, is not a supported operatin in python.
2 possible solutions:

1. Use list comprehension:

   ```
   weights=[(1/(ampserr_el)**(2))+1e-8) for ampserr_el in ampserr]
   ```
2. Use numpy to turn `ampserr` into an array, which supports scalar exponentiation:

   ```
   ampserr = np.array(ampserr) # now the ** operator will work
   ```